# If $f$ is zero in the interior, $f$ has zero integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, riemann-integration

Let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ be bounded, where $A$ is some box in $\mathbb{R}^d$. Suppose that $f(A^{\circ}) = 0$. I want to show that $\int_{A}fdx = 0$. So my approach is: Let $P$ be a partition of the box $A$ to equi-volume boxes. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the set of boxes generated by the partition. For $C\in\mathcal{C}$, let $M_C=\sup\limits_{x\in C}f(x)$, $m_C = \inf\limits_{x\in C}f(x)$. Then the upper sum for the partition is
$$
U(f,P) = \sum\limits_{C\in\mathcal{C}}M_CVol(C) = \sum\limits_{C\in\mathcal{C},\ C\cap\partial A = \varnothing}M_CVol(C) + \sum\limits_{C\in\mathcal{C},\ C\cap\partial A\neq\varnothing}M_CVol(C)
$$
By hypothesis, only the second summand can be non zero, hence
$$
U(f,P) = \sum\limits_{C\in\mathcal{C},\ C\cap\partial A\neq\varnothing}M_CVol(C)
$$
Since $f$ is globally bounded, then for some $L$, $L\geq M_C$ for all $C\in\mathcal{C}$, hence
$$
U(f,P) \leq L\sum\limits_{C\in\mathcal{C}, C\cap\partial A\neq\varnothing}Vol(C)
$$
Since the partition is of equi-volume boxes, $Vol(C) = \frac{Vol(A)}{n}$ where $n$ is the number of boxes. We therefore get that
$$
U(f,P)\leq LVol(A)\frac{k}{n}
$$
where $k$ is the number of boxes in the partition that intersect the boundary. The difference between general dimension and 1D is that in 1D, $k = 2$ always. For higher dimensions, $k = k(n)$, so information on $\frac{k}{n}$ is needed in order to decrease the RHS to be arbitrarily small, and this is where I am stuck

Comment: You need to be careful that your boxes are not degenerating. For example if you only subdivide in one direction, your boxes will get ever smaller, but all of them will touch the boundary. You are on the right track, but try to subdivide evenly, lets say into a grid of $l$ times $l$ times ... times $l$ boxes. Then it is not hard to see how many boxes touch a single side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_A f = \int_{\partial A} f + \int_{A^{\circ}} f = \int_{\partial A} f \leq \textbf{max} (f) \cdot \mu_{\mathbb{R}^d}(\partial A)$$
Since $\textbf{dim}(\partial A) = d-1$, what can you say about $\mu_{\mathbb{R}^d}(\partial A)$?

Answer (score 0):

Because $A$ is a box, you can safely assume that each $C$ is a box and that there are $\sqrt[d]{n}$ boxes along each dimension. Now, in $k$ dimensions, a box has a boundary composed of $2d$ boxes of dimension $d-1$, and each of these boxes can be covered with $\sqrt[d]{n}^{d-1}$ boxes, so $k=2d\cdot\sqrt[d]{n}^{d-1}$ and you can now estimate $\frac{k}{n}$ to see it becomes arbitrarily small.

Comment: Hello. I've been out of measure theory for some time, but does the argument I present work as well?